# Laptop boots directly to Windows, Ubuntu alredy installed and refind not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So i have this weird problem on a HP laptop Atheros.  I first installed windows 7 and then Trusty Tahr,both on Uefi mode with the gpt partition.

The problem is that when i turn it on, it goes directly to Windows without displaying the GRUB screen.  If I press F9 to go to the Boot menu I can see that first comes the "OS boot manager" and then Refind and then Ubuntu.

being able to boot both

In the BIOS menu I go to the boot order to see if I can change it but only the "os boot manager" option appears.  Maybe this is a partition problem? I don't know, but I have to fix this.  Please help.

Answer (score 5):

HP BIOSes are a bit weird, I've been struggling with that, too.

Does your BIOS Setup look like this (found on newer HP ProBooks), then follow below instructions. This was the only way I managed to get Ubuntu to boot on my laptop with Secure Boot enabled.

[image]

In the BIOS setup, under *System Configuration* → *Boot Options*, you should find the option *Customized Boot* (Bottom checkbox in below picture). Activate it.

[image]

Then scroll a bit further down, to the boot order. Here, you should be able to put `customized boot` before OS Boot Manager.

[image]

Then go down a bit further, where you'll find the option to set up the *Customized Boot*. There you can select *Add*. In the now opening text entry, enter the following line:

```
EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

[image]

Press enter, save the settings, and quit the BIOS setup. Then your computer should boot into GRUB, from where you can select the OS.

As for rEFInd, I am not doal booting and I don't know it very well, but I've read already that rEFInd stores its EFI file as the GRUB EFI, so just try it. If you manage to boot Ubuntu, and the rEFInd screen doesn't show up, browse `/boot/efi` for the correct EFI file.

Comment: Well My BIOS was really different i didt find the customized option, so i mounted the Efi partition and replaced windows EFI file with th Refind one and it seems to work, now computer Boots into Refind Main menuand i am able to pick systems it seems that did the trick 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @AhoraSoyUnCuervo Please post that as a separate answer and accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well My BIOS was really different i didt find the customized option, so i mounted the Efi partition and replaced windows EFI file with th Refind one and it seems to work, now computer Boots into Refind Main menuand i am able to pick systems it seems that did the trick now its working perfectly :D

Comment: This is basically the alternative naming option described [in the rEFInd documentation.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming) Unfortunately, some EFIs are buggy and don't remember their boot options.